# Inserir password entityframework

Tags: entity-framework

Estou tentando inserir um usuário que já existe em outro banco de dados, porém no banco de dados anterior, não existia a validação do entity framework, então por exemplo, a senha poderia ser 123456.

Então quando utilizo este comando:

```
 var resultado = _userManager.CreateAsync(user, usuario.Senha.Trim()).Result;
```

Porém ai ele retorna o erro de que a senha não está validada, que falta caracteres, e etc.
Como posso contornar, apenas para inserir esses dados ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando vc configura o asp.net identity você defini regras de como ele deve ser comportar, por exemplo:

```
services.AddIdentity<AspNetUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
})
```

- Requer 6 digitos
- Não requer digitos
- Não requer letras minusculas
- Não requer alfanumericos
- Não requer letras maisuculas